# How to normalize a numpy array to a unit vector

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, statistics, normalization

I would like to convert a NumPy array to a unit vector. More specifically, I am looking for an equivalent version of this normalisation function:

```
def normalize(v):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(v)
    if norm == 0: 
       return v
    return v / norm
```

This function handles the situation where vector `v` has the norm value of 0.

Is there any similar functions provided in `sklearn` or `numpy`?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written?

Comment: If this is really a concern, you should check for norm < epsilon, where epsilon is a small tolerance. In addition, I wouldn't silently pass back a norm zero vector, I would `raise` an exception!

Comment: my function works but I would like to know if there is something inside the python's more common library. I am writing different machine learning functions and I would like to avoid to define too much new functions to make the code more clear and readable

Comment: I did a few quick tests and I found that `x/np.linalg.norm(x)` was not much slower (about 15-20%) than `x/np.sqrt((x**2).sum())` in numpy 1.15.1 on a CPU.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

If you're using scikit-learn you can use [`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.normalize):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

x = np.random.rand(1000)*10
norm1 = x / np.linalg.norm(x)
norm2 = normalize(x[:,np.newaxis], axis=0).ravel()
print np.all(norm1 == norm2)
# True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but are you sure that sklearn.preprocessing.normalize works also with vector of shape=(n,) or (n,1) ?  I am having some problems with this library

Comment: `normalize` requires a 2D input. You can pass the `axis=` argument to specify whether you want to apply the normalization across the rows or columns of your input array.

Comment: Note that the 'norm' argument of the normalize function can be either 'l1' or 'l2' and the default is 'l2'. If you want your vector's sum to be 1 (e.g. a probability distribution) you should use norm='l1' in the normalize function.

Comment: Also note that `np.linalg.norm(x)` calculates 'l2' norm by default. If you want your vector's sum to be 1 you should use `np.linalg.norm(x, ord=1)`

Comment: Note: x must be `ndarray` for it to work with the `normalize()` function. Otherwise it can be a `list`.

Comment: NOTE: calculation for norm1 is much faster. `%%timeit` for norm1 calculation gives: `4.74 µs ± 24.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`, whereas for norm2 it is: `34.2 µs ± 473 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

Answer (score 66):

I agree that it would be nice if such a function were part of the included libraries. But it isn't, as far as I know. So here is a version for arbitrary axes that gives optimal performance.

```
import numpy as np

def normalized(a, axis=-1, order=2):
    l2 = np.atleast_1d(np.linalg.norm(a, order, axis))
    l2[l2==0] = 1
    return a / np.expand_dims(l2, axis)

A = np.random.randn(3,3,3)
print(normalized(A,0))
print(normalized(A,1))
print(normalized(A,2))

print(normalized(np.arange(3)[:,None]))
print(normalized(np.arange(3)))
```

Comment: I did not deeply test the ali_m solution but in some simple case it seems to  be working. Are there situtions where your function does better?

Comment: I don't know; but it works over arbitrary axes, and we have explicit control over what happens for length 0 vectors.

Comment: Very nice!  This should be in numpy — although order should probably come before axis in my opinion.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn Curious to understand why order=2 chosen over others?

Comment: Because the Euclidian/pythagoran norm happens to be the most frequently used one; wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Pretty late, but I think it's worth mentioning that this is exactly why it is discouraged to use lowercase 'L' as a variable name... in my typeface 'l2' is indistinguishable from '12'

Comment: normalizing `[inf,  1,  2]` yields `[nan, 0, 0]`, but shouldn't it be `[1, 0, 0]`?

Comment: If you'd like to endow the fp-inf symbol with such semantics, sure, but thatd be kinda nonstandard. The fp standard is full of quirks anyway but I think having such a function do anything but standard fp logic by default would just be confusing.

Comment: Shouldn't the normalized array sum up to 1 (at least I would expect it to do)? Just tested this implementation with `[5,5]` what yields `[0.70710678, 0.70710678]` what in sum is about `1.41`. Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Look up the concept of the order of a norm. What you want is the 1-norm, which you can get by setting the order kwarg to 1.

Comment: @bendl I think that's exactly why it's encouraged to use a better typeface

Comment: Regarding choice of variable name `l2`, most python users are not software engineers. They are mathematicians and scientists first, and their code tends to reflect that culture, where using single letters for variables is customary. I agree though. Using lowercase `l` or uppercase `O` as a variable names should *definitely* be avoided. Trust me, I fix software bugs for a living.

Comment: @pasbi then what should `[inf, 3, inf]` yield? `[1, 0, 1]` or `[0.5, 0, 0.5]` or something else? I'd say `[nan, 0, nan]` would be the right output so the user can then fill the `nan` values with your chosen filler to force the expectation.

Comment: @scign I guess there's no right or wrong here, just more or less useful. I agree that your proposal is probably more useful in general. It's also more IEEE 754-conform (as `∞/∞=nan`). I don't remember my use case from four years ago, I presume it was something very special.

Answer (score 43):

This might also work for you

```
import numpy as np
normalized_v = v / np.sqrt(np.sum(v**2))
```

but fails when `v` has length 0.

In that case, introducing a small constant to prevent the zero division solves this.

As proposed in the comments one could also use

```
v/np.linalg.norm(v)
```

Comment: Or `v/np.linalg.norm(v)`

Comment: added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks for the contribution @testing_22

Answer (score 29):

To avoid zero division I use eps, but that's maybe not great.

```
def normalize(v):
    norm=np.linalg.norm(v)
    if norm==0:
        norm=np.finfo(v.dtype).eps
    return v/norm
```

Comment: normalizing `[inf,  1,  2]` yields `[nan, 0, 0]`, but shouldn't it be `[1, 0, 0]`?

Comment: Some time has passed but the answer is no, `[nan, 0, 0]` is correct since the norm is `inf` and `inf/inf` is an indeterminate form because `<everything>/inf` is `0` but is also true that `inf/<everything>` is `inf`, so `inf/inf` cannot be determined.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use the L1-norm? The OP seems to ask for L2-normalization.

Comment: hm yeah should have been l2 norm

Answer (score 12):

If you have multidimensional data and want each axis normalized to its max or its sum:

```
def normalize(_d, to_sum=True, copy=True):
    # d is a (n x dimension) np array
    d = _d if not copy else np.copy(_d)
    d -= np.min(d, axis=0)
    d /= (np.sum(d, axis=0) if to_sum else np.ptp(d, axis=0))
    return d
```

Uses numpys [peak to peak](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) function.

```
a = np.random.random((5, 3))

b = normalize(a, copy=False)
b.sum(axis=0) # array([1., 1., 1.]), the rows sum to 1

c = normalize(a, to_sum=False, copy=False)
c.max(axis=0) # array([1., 1., 1.]), the max of each row is 1
```

Comment: Watch out if all values are the same in the original matrix, then ptp would be 0. Division by 0 will return nan.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't need utmost precision, your function can be reduced to:

```
v_norm = v / (np.linalg.norm(v) + 1e-16)
```

Answer (score 11):

There is also the function `unit_vector()` to normalize vectors in the popular [transformations](https://pypi.org/project/transformations/) module by Christoph Gohlke:

```
import transformations as trafo
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])

print(trafo.unit_vector(data, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 9):

You mentioned sci-kit learn, so I want to share another solution.

#### sci-kit learn `MinMaxScaler`

In sci-kit learn, there is a API called `MinMaxScaler` which can customize the the value range as you like.

It also deal with NaN issues for us.

> NaNs are treated as missing values: disregarded in fit, and maintained
>   in transform. ... see reference [1]

#### Code sample

The code is simple, just type

```
# Let's say X_train is your input dataframe
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# call MinMaxScaler object
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
# feed in a numpy array
X_train_norm = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train.values)
# wrap it up if you need a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(X_train_norm)
```

Reference

- [1]  [sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)

Comment: This does a different type of transform. The OP wanted to scale the magnitude of the vector so that each vector has a length of 1; MinMaxScaler individually scales each column independently to be within a certain range.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to normalize n dimensional feature vectors stored in a 3D tensor, you could also use PyTorch:

```
import numpy as np
from torch import from_numpy
from torch.nn.functional import normalize

vecs = np.random.rand(3, 16, 16, 16)
norm_vecs = normalize(from_numpy(vecs), dim=0, eps=1e-16).numpy()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you work with multidimensional array following fast solution is possible.

Say we have 2D array, which we want to normalize by last axis, while some rows have zero norm.

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [5, 6, 7]
], dtype=np.float)

lengths = np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=-1)
print(lengths)  # [ 3.74165739  0.         10.48808848]
arr[lengths > 0] = arr[lengths > 0] / lengths[lengths > 0][:, np.newaxis]
print(arr)
# [[0.26726124 0.53452248 0.80178373]
# [0.         0.         0.        ]
# [0.47673129 0.57207755 0.66742381]]
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're working with 3D vectors, you can do this concisely using the toolbelt [vg](https://github.com/lace/vg). It's a light layer on top of numpy and it supports single values and stacked vectors.

```
import numpy as np
import vg

x = np.random.rand(1000)*10
norm1 = x / np.linalg.norm(x)
norm2 = vg.normalize(x)
print np.all(norm1 == norm2)
# True
```

I created the library at my last startup, where it was motivated by uses like this: simple ideas which are way too verbose in NumPy.

Answer (score 7):

Without `sklearn` and using just `numpy`.
Just define a function:.

**Assuming that the *rows are the variables* and *the columns the samples* (`axis= 1`):**

```
import numpy as np

# Example array
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

def stdmtx(X):
    means = X.mean(axis =1)
    stds = X.std(axis= 1, ddof=1)
    X= X - means[:, np.newaxis]
    X= X / stds[:, np.newaxis]
    return np.nan_to_num(X)
```

**output:**

```
X
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

stdmtx(X)
array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: These output arrays do not have unit norm. Subtracting the mean and giving the samples unit variance does not produce unit vectors.

Answer (score 5):

For a 2D array, you can use the following one-liner to normalize across rows. To normalize across columns, simply set `axis=0`.

```
a / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `keepdims=True`, that's truly useful for shape-invariant case

Answer (score 1):

If you want all values in [0; 1] `for 1d-array` then just use

```
(a - a.min(axis=0)) / (a.max(axis=0) - a.min(axis=0))
```

Where `a` is your `1d-array`.

An example:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2])
>>> (a - a.min(axis=0)) / (a.max(axis=0) - a.min(axis=0))
array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1. , 0.4])
```

**Note for the method.** For saving proportions between values there is a restriction: `1d-array` must have at least one `0` and consists of `0` and `positive` numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A simple dot product would do the job. No need for any extra package.

```
x = x/np.sqrt(x.dot(x))
```

By the way, if the norm of `x` is zero, it is inherently a zero vector, and cannot be converted to a unit vector (which has norm 1). If you want to catch the case of `np.array([0,0,...0])`, then use

```
norm = np.sqrt(x.dot(x))
x = x/norm if norm != 0 else x
```

Comment: I often use this trick:

   x_normalised = x / (norm+(norm==0))

so in all cases where the norm is zero, you just divide by one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the simple solution `x/numpy.linalg.norm(x)` doesn't work if `x` is an array of vectors. But with a simple `reshape()` you can force it into a flat list, use a list comprehension, and use `reshape()` again to get back the original shape.

```
s=x.shape
np.array([ v/np.linalg.norm(v)  for v in x.reshape(-1, s[-1])]).reshape(s)
```

First we store the shape of the array

```
s=x.shape
```

Then we reshape it into a simple (one-dimensional) array of vectors

```
x.reshape(-1, s[-1])
```

by making use of the '-1' argument of `reshape()` which essentially means "take as many as it needs", e.g . if `x` was a (4,5,3) array, `x.reshape(-1,3)` would be of shape (20,3). The use of `s[-1]` allows for an arbitrary dimension of the vectors.

Then we use a list comprehension to step through the array and calculate the unit vector one vector at a time

```
[ v/np.linalg.norm(v)  for v in x.reshape(-1, s[-1])]
```

and finally we turn it back into an numpy array and give it back its original shape

```
np.array([ v/np.linalg.norm(v)  for v in x.reshape(-1, s[-1])]).reshape(s)
```