# Generate random probability in Python

Tags: python, probability, distribution

I want to genearte different probabilities in a range of [0,1]. The only things which changes is the number of the probabilities, so for example in my code below I wanted to generate 4 numbers randomly five times. My main problem is that with my code they don't sum up to 1. How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

```
def generateRandom():
    for i in range (0,5):
        data_uniform = uniform.rvs(size=4, loc = 0.0, scale=1)
        sum_uni=0
        for i in range(0,len(data_uniform)):
            sum_uni+=data_uniform[i]
        print(data_uniform,sum_uni)
```

Comment: After you got your numbers, calculate the sum of these numbers and divide each with that sum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1#18659948 Does this help?

Comment: Or this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895218/create-an-array-that-sums-to-a-specific-number

Comment: Thank you guys. @np8 answer worked out for me. Please submit a solution to accept it :) But you can also submit a solution too guys, and I will upvote it because I tried now these solutions too and they also work.