# Normalization VS. numpy way to normalize?

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I'm supposed to normalize an array. I've read about normalization and come across a formula:

[image]

I wrote the following function for it:

```
def normalize_list(list):
    max_value = max(list)
    min_value = min(list)
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        list[i] = (list[i] - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
```

That is supposed to normalize an array of elements.

Then I have come across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21031303/6209399
Which says you can normalize an array by simply doing this:

```
def normalize_list_numpy(list):
    normalized_list = list / np.linalg.norm(list)
    return normalized_list
```

---

If I normalize this test array `test_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` with my own function and with the numpy method, I get these answers:

```
My own function: [0.0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0]
The numpy way: [0.059234887775909233, 0.11846977555181847, 0.17770466332772769, 0.23693955110363693, 0.29617443887954614, 0.35540932665545538, 0.41464421443136462, 0.47387910220727386, 0.5331139899831830
```

---

Why do the functions give different answers? Is there others way to normalize an array of data? What does `numpy.linalg.norm(list)` do? What do I get wrong?

Comment: Just so you're aware, this isn't the traditional formula for normalization, which is usually expressed as (x - x_mean) / stdev(x), which standardizes x to be normally distributed.  (stdev is standard deviation.)

Comment: Agree with Brad. Your formula scales the values to the interval [0, 1], while "normalization" more often means transforming to have mean 0 and variance 1 (in statistics), or scaling a vector to have unit length with respect to some norm (usually L2).

Comment: Isn't that called 'Standardization'? @phg

Comment: @OuuGiii No, without having an official reference to cite I would say that both "normalization" and "standardization" refer to subtracting out a mean and dividing by a standard deviation to get the data to have an N~(0,1) distribution.  Maybe normalization could take on the meaning you mention in linear algebra contexts, but I would say phg's is the dominant usage.

Comment: I've tried the way you said it @BradSolomon by "x - x_mean) / stdev(x)", it still doesn't give the same answer for the numpy way to normalize a list. What does the numpy way do?

Comment: `normalize_list_numpy` as you have it defined is something completely different from the type of scaling that I'm talking about and that @utengr mentions also.  This isn't "the NumPy way", it's just NumPy's way of implementing that specific definition of scaling.  My point is mathematically, they're two totally different things.

Comment: @OuuGiii yes, according to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10298/112762) at least, **normalization** refers to a [0,1] range, and **standardization** refers to a mean 0 variance 1.

Comment: Now that you see that "normalize" is context-dependent, ask the person who told you what you are supposed to do what meant. Don't ask other people to guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are different types of normalization. You are using min-max normalization. The min-max normalization from scikit learn is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

# your function
def normalize_list(list_normal):
    max_value = max(list_normal)
    min_value = min(list_normal)
    for i in range(len(list_normal)):
        list_normal[i] = (list_normal[i] - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
    return list_normal

#Scikit learn version 
def normalize_list_numpy(list_numpy):
    normalized_list = minmax_scale(list_numpy)
    return normalized_list

test_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
test_array_numpy = np.array(test_array)

print(normalize_list(test_array))
print(normalize_list_numpy(test_array_numpy))
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0]    
[0.0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0]
```

MinMaxscaler uses exactly your formula for normalization/scaling:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html

@OuuGiii: **NOTE:** It is not a good idea to use Python built-in function names as varibale names. `list()` is a Python builtin function so its use as a variable should be avoided.

Comment: Didn't know this existed, +1.  @OuuGii directly from the docs for this function, "This transformation is often used as an alternative to zero mean, unit variance scaling."

Comment: @BradSolomon Its used quite often in sklearn for feature scaling before they are fed to various sensitive classifiers such as svm or knn etc.

Answer (score 8):

The question/answer that you reference doesn't explicitly relate your own formula to the `np.linalg.norm(list)` version that you use here.

One NumPy solution would be this:

```
import numpy as np
def normalize(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    return (x - x.min()) / (np.ptp(x))

print(normalize(test_array))    
# [ 0.     0.125  0.25   0.375  0.5    0.625  0.75   0.875  1.   ]
```

Here [`np.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) is peak-to-peak ie

> Range of values (maximum - minimum) along an axis.

This approach scales the values to the interval [0, 1] as pointed out by @phg.

The more traditional definition of normalization would be to scale to a 0 mean and unit variance:

```
x = np.asarray(test_array)
res = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
print(res.mean(), res.std())
# 0.0 1.0
```

Or use `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` as a pre-canned function.

Using `test_array / np.linalg.norm(test_array)` creates a result that is of unit length; you'll see that `np.linalg.norm(test_array / np.linalg.norm(test_array))` equals 1.  So you're talking about two different fields here, one being statistics and the other being linear algebra.

Comment: thank you, but what then does the function normalize_list_numpy() do?

Comment: @OuuGiii it makes the vector have length 1.

Comment: @OuuGiii see the result of `np.linalg.norm(test_array / np.linalg.norm(test_array))` to understand @phg's comment.

Answer (score 2):

The power of python is its [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) property, which allows you to do vectorizing array operations without explicit looping. So, You do not need to write a function using explicit for loop, which is slow and time-consuming, especially if your dataset is too big.

The pythonic way of doing [min-max normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Methods) is

```
test_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
normalized_test_array = (test_array - min(test_array)) / (max(test_array) - min(test_array))
```

> output >> [ 0.,     0.125,  0.25,   0.375,  0.5,    0.625,  0.75,   0.875,  1.   ]