# Scale a numpy array with from -0.1 - 0.2 to 0-255

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have an numpy array in python that represent an image its size is 28x28x3 while the max value of it is 0.2 and the min is -0.1. I want to scale that image between 0-255. How can I do so?

Comment: You may want to check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030391/how-to-normalize-an-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
new_arr = ((arr + 0.1) * (1/0.3) * 255).astype('uint8')
```

This first scales the vector to the [0, 1] range, multiplies it by 255 and then converts it to `uint8`, which is a common format for images (opencv uses it, for example)

In general you can use:

```
new_arr = ((arr - arr.min()) * (1/(arr.max() - arr.min()) * 255)).astype('uint8')
```

Comment: It's probably a bit better (though ugly) to use s.th. like `255.999` to have equal bin sizes.

Comment: Probably better to just use `np.round`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use uint8 datatype while storing the image from numpy array.

`import numpy as np
 from PIL import Image
 img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(tmp))`

tmp is my np array of size 255*255*3.