# How To Normalize Array Between 1 and 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array with the following integer numbers:

```
[10 30 16 18 24 18 30 30 21 7 15 14 24 27 14 16 30 12 18]
```

I want to normalize them to a range between 1 and 10.

I know that the general formula to normalize arrays is:

[image]

But how am I supposed to scale them between 1 and 10?

**Question:** What is the simplest/fastest way to normalize this array to values between 1 and 10?

Comment: Get them between 0 and 1 and then multiply by 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030391/how-to-normalize-an-array-in-numpy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @NaorTedgi that's not a good dupe: OP already knows how to normalize an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your range is actually 9 long: from 1 to 10. If you multiply the normalized array by 9 you get values from 0 to 9, which you need to shift back by 1:

```
start = 1
end = 10
width = end - start
res = (arr - arr.min())/(arr.max() - arr.min()) * width + start
```

Note that the denominator here has a numpy built-in named [`arr.ptp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ptp.html):

```
res = (arr - arr.min())/arr.ptp() * width + start
```