# Normalizing vectors contained in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, divide-by-zero, normalize

I've got an array, called X, where every element is a 2d-vector itself. The diagonal of this array is filled with nothing but zero-vectors.
Now I need to normalize every vector in this array, without changing the structure of it.

First I tried to calculate the norm of every vector and put it in an array, called N. After that I wanted to divide every element of X by every element of N. 
Two problems occured to me:

1) Many entries of N are zero, which is obviously a problem when I try to divide by them.

2) The shapes of the arrays don't match, so np.divide() doesn't work as expected.

Beyond that I don't think, that it's a good idea to calculate N like this, because later on I want to be able to do the same with more than two vectors.

```
import numpy as np

# Example array
X = np.array([[[0, 0], [1, -1]], [[-1, 1], [0, 0]]])
# Array containing the norms
N = np.vstack((np.linalg.norm(X[0], axis=1), np.linalg.norm(X[1], 
axis=1)))
R = np.divide(X, N)
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
R = np.array([[[0, 0], [0.70710678, -0.70710678]], [[-0.70710678, 0.70710678], [0, 0]]])
```

Comment: What is D, above? Can you provide a definition so I can try and run your code?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030391/how-to-normalize-an-array-in-numpy

Comment: @jerremaier see my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: If dividing by the norm is all you wish to do but have cases where the norm is 0 you could use `f = lambda Y: Y / np.linalg.norm(Y) if np.linalg.norm(Y) else 0` and use the list comprehension from @serafeim. [Norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) shouldn't be 0 unless the whole array is filled with 0s [or significantly small numbers :) ]

Comment: @HaydenEastwood D is supposed to be X, sorry. I fixed my mistake

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for and I really like the short solution. Is there a particular reason you use ```lambda``` instead of a function defintion?

Comment: @jerremaier NP. You can always use the `def f(Y): ...` pattern but I figured the whole function was a one liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `sklearn`. Just define a function and then use list comprehension:

Assuming that the 0th dimension of the X is equal to the number of 2D arrays that you have, use this:

```
import numpy as np

# Example array
X = np.array([[[0, 0], [1, -1]], [[-1, 1], [0, 0]]])

def stdmtx(X):
    X= X - X.mean(axis =1)[:, np.newaxis]
    X= X / X.std(axis= 1, ddof=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    return np.nan_to_num(X)

R = np.array([stdmtx(X[i,:,:]) for i in range(X.shape[0])])
```

**The desired output `R`:**

```
array([[[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.70710678, -0.70710678]],

       [[-0.70710678,  0.70710678],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ]]])
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This really does the job! I just don't completely understand how you calculate the norm in your function.

Comment: I calculate the means and the standard deviations of each variable individually and then I remove the variable specific mean and  divide by the variable specific std each variable

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer since it addresses correctly your question