# Can python normalize array of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing an assignment for machine learning class in python. I started learning python just yesterday so I am not aware of practices used in python.

Part of my task is to load data from csv (2D array) lets call it `arr_2d` and normalize that.

I've found `sklearn` and `numpy` solutions online but they expect 2D array as input.

My approach after loading `arr_2d` is to parse them into array of objects (`data: [HealthRecord]`).

My solution was a code similar to this (note: kinda pseudocode)

```
result = [] # 2D array of property values
for key in ['age','height','weight',...]:
    tmp = list(map(lambda item: getattr(key, item), data))
    result.append(tmp)
```

Result now contains `3 * data.length` items and I would use `sklearn` to normalize single row in my `result` array, then rotate it back and parse normalized to `HealthRecord`.

**I see this as overcomplicated and what I would like to see an option to do it any easier way, like sending `[HealthRecord]` to `sklearn.normalize`**

---

Code below shows my (simplified) loading and parsing:

```
class Person: 
    age: int
    height: int
    weight: int
    

def arr_2_obj(data: [[]]) -> Person:
    person = Person()
    person.age = data[0]
    person.height = data[1]
    person.weight = data[2]

    return person


# age (days), height (cm), weight (kg)
input = [
    [60*365, 125, 65],
    [30*365, 195, 125],
    [13*365, 116, 53],
    [16*365, 164, 84],
    [12*365, 125, 96],
    [10*365, 90, 46],    
]

parsed = []

for row in input:
    parsed.append(arr_2_obj(row))
```

note: `Person` class is `HealthRecord`

Thank you for any input or insights.

Edit: typo sci-learn -> sklearn

Comment: Id like to add that real length of parsed CSV is 70000*13. Also that i am parsing data to class for easier manipulation. After loading dataset i am cleaning rows based on incorrect or out of range values and coding text values to numerical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to normalize an array in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030391/how-to-normalize-an-array-in-numpy)

Comment: @Joe No it does not. I am aware of thread you mentioned and as I stated in my question I was looking for another approach. Said thread considers 2D array as input, while I'd like to pass array of objects to normalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. In practice, you're dealing with tabular data. The standard (as in most popular, not standard library) package in python to process tabular data is `pandas`, so you can do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([d.__dict__ for d in data])
normalized_df = (df-df.mean())/df.std() # example normalization
```

If you insist on dealing with arrays of objects instead of tables, you can write a class which does the required conversions to shorten notations, e.g. something like

```py
class ObjectList: 
    def __init__(self, object_type, records): 
        self.objects = [object_type(**record) for record in records]

    def to_data_frame(self): 
        return pd.DataFrame([d.__dict__ for d in self.objects])

class PersonList(ObjectList): 
    def __init__(self, records): 
        super().__init__(Person, records)
```

The above assumes `class Person` has an `__init__` function accepting arguments `height`, `age`, `weight`.

You can also try to shorten notations further by overloading operators, but unless you're writing library code I don't see why you would want to.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm marking 'you cant' as right answer. I was already loading CSV with pandas as `DataFrame` but using it on my 4MB csv (70000 rows, 13cols) it takes much much longer. What approach and structure do you propose?
edit: by longer i meant working with DataFrame.values instead whole DataFrame was way faster

Comment: pandas.read_csv is the fastest way I know to read a csv in python (contrary to numpy functions for that), after that it depends specifically what computations you're doing with it - generally for machine learning you need your data in numeric form, i.e. as numpy ndarrays or tensors, you may need to translate categorical fields to 1-hot vectors, eliminate fields you're perhaps not going to directly use such as strings etc. In any case you need a bunch of matrices for computations eventually.